# Error in switch statement, Javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I got a function that should return a result depending on a dealed Black Jack hand. I used a switch statement for this, eventhough I'm not sure you could use multiple switch in a function. Anyhow I got an error saying 'missing ; before statement' after the first 'result' text in the first 'case'. This code is what I have been taught so I'm not sure where I did go wrong. Could you please give me a hint or anything, please? Refards, Thomas.

```
function printResult(playResult, dealResult) {
var text = "";
switch(playResult) {
    case (playResult == 21) : result "black jack";
    break;
    case (playResult > 21) : result "busted";
    break;
    case (playResult < 21) : result "safe";
    break;
}

switch(dealResult) {
    case (dealResult < 17) : result "safe";
    break;
    case (dealResult == 17 && < 21) : result "stop";
    break;
    case (dealResult == 21) : result "black jack";
    break;
}

return result;
}

var result = "Player: " + playResult + ", Dealer: " + dealResult;


ANSWER = (printResult(5+9+10, 6+3+7));
```

Comment: Hmm, find (and read/follow) a tutorial / reference on [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Because making stuff up "won't work". Perhaps you meant to use an [`if .. else if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)? (The value after the `case` keyword *must* be a string or number literal. Once that is fixed, or avoided, work on each other syntax error, one at a time - consult a reference/tutorial until they are all gone.)

Comment: Validate your code: [jshint.com](http://jshint.com)

Comment: `result "black jack";` is a syntax error. And has nothing to do with the `switch` that surrounds it.

Comment: @user2864740 When you say it that simple I have to thank you. if/elseif seems more logical now that you say it.

Comment: Also, in response to a comment in your question, you definitely CAN have multiple switch statements in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want result to be a variable assigment?

```
result = "black jack"
```

or maybe a return?

```
return "black jack"
```

Comment: Does this *really* **answer** the question?

Comment: @TimLewis: Yes, the question is to identify the source of the `'missing ; before statement'` error. Of course there are many other things to be corrected :-)

Comment: If there's many other things to be corrected, correct them! I only ask this because this isn't (in my opinion anyway) a complete answer. But someone else agrees and someone else thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all of the playResult variables inside of the switch block.

In addition, switch does not support higher than or lower than so a if is better suited for this situation.

```
function printResult(playResult, dealResult) {

  var result;

  if(playResult == 21) {
    result = "black jack";
  } else if(playResult > 21) {
    result = "busted";
  } else {
    result = "safe";
  }

  if(dealResult < 17) {
    result = "stop";
  } else if(dealResult == 17 && dealResult < 21) {
    result = "stop";
  } else {
    result = "black jack";
  }

  return result;
}

var result = "Player: " + playResult + ", Dealer: " + dealResult;

ANSWER = (printResult(5+9+10, 6+3+7));
```

This is a lot closer, but there is still problems with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do "if logic" in the case statement; that's not how a switch works.  A switch is going to take the value of `dealResult` and do a straight compare.

```
switch(dealResult)
{
    case 21: //dealResult MUST be 21
       result = 'blackjack!'
       break;
    case 20: //dealResult MUST be 20
       //etc..
       break;
    case >20: //not valid, will break
}
```

As far as I know, if you need to do > and < compares, you should be using an if -> else block.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your function, even if you get the switch working i don't think the logic is what you're aiming it to be.

If the purpose of the function is tell you who won the game, ergo the result as your name implies then you need to first put the rules down.. lets just for readability write it in pseudo..

Where either player has blackjack check the following

1. Player Blackjack to Dealer Blackjack = Push (Draw)
2. Player Blackjack to Dealer Anything = Player Win
3. Player Anything to Dealer Blackjack = Dealer Win

Then check if one is bust, to win a player must of held

1. Player > 21 = Dealer Win
2. Player <=21 and Dealer > 21 = Player Win

After that, we can do the simple checks.

1. Player == Dealer = Push
2. Player > Dealer = Player Win
3. Player < Dealer = Dealer Win

You can't really use a switch statement effectively to do this. You 'can' use it but for something like this, if else will suffice.

```
function blackJackWinnerIs(player, dealer)
{
   if((player == 21) || (dealer==21))
   {
      if(player > dealer)
         return "Player";
      else if (player < dealer)
         return "Dealer";
      else
         return "Push";
   }
   else if(player > 21) 
      return "Dealer";
   else if(dealer > 21) // already checked if player<=21
      return "Player";
   else if(player > dealer)
      return "Player";
   else if(dealer > player)
      return "Dealer";
   else return "Push";
}
var hands = [
   {player:21,dealer:21},
   {player:20,dealer:21},
   {player:21,dealer:17},
   {player:22,dealer:17},
   {player:17,dealer:22},
   {player:19,dealer:18},
   {player:18,dealer:20},
   {player:20,dealer:20}
];
for(var i=0; i<hands.length;i++)
{
   var winner = blackJackWinnerIs(hands[i].player,hands[i].dealer);
   console.log("Player:",hands[i].player," Dealer:",hands[i].dealer," => Winner:",winner);
}
```

This is functional.. but it won't protect you from bad inputs e.g. if you accidentally passed in two nulls you would get a "push" result when really you should either send out an error or void the game... but thats all on you.